# GitLab pages URL is not what I expect

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I'v been at this for ages and I can't get the gitlab.io url to be correct for my github pages.

I created a group called `lodjit-public` and in there I created a project called `lodjit-www.gitlab.io`.

I expect to be able to find the page at `lodjit-www.gitlab.io` but it's telling me the page is at `lodjit-public.gitlab.io/lodjit-www.gitlab.io`...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab defines how your group and project name are mapped to the gitlab.io domain. The group name becomes the host name in the URL, the project name becomes a path in the URL. If you want a different hostname, you must use a corresponding username or groupname.

See the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#gitlab-pages-domain-names

Comment: That seems to make sense... So I need to create a group called `lodjit-www` and a project `lodjit-www.gitlab.io`?

Answer (score 1):

Your pages URLs should have been  :
https://lodjit-public.gitlab.io/lodjit-www%2Egitlab%2Eio

Considering your last changes it’s now:
https://lodjit-www.gitlab.io/lodjit-www%2Egitlab%2Eio

Note: The ‘dot’ in your project has been replaced by %2E in the url.

Indeed, all the special characters of your organisation/group/project names must be escaped regarding urn-encoding rules.

See gitlab documentation for details: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#gitlab-pages-domain-names